# Detect Background Color Change in Google Spreadsheet with Apps Script

Tags: events, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created an `onEdit()` trigger in Google App Script, but it only works when I change the value of a cell; not when I change the background color. How can I fix it?

Comment: That's not possible, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11067652/1536038

Comment: How does the background color change?  From code?  User changes it?

Comment: Thanks guys, I suspected kind of that. I was just hoping from 2012 till 2015 google team had made some progress in that! The color is user changed.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: There is an open issue about onChange(e) to report that it's not working. See [Google script onChange event doens't fire anymore](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37454842)

---

Instead of using onEdit(e) use onChange(e). When the background of a cell be changed, the value of e.changeType will be FORMAT.

```
function onChange(e) {
   // Show a popup with a message showing the type of change.
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(e.changeType);
}
```

**References**

- [Events Objects - Google Apps Scripts Guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: This does not work anymore. Has `onChange` been depreciated?

Comment: @X_Trust: There is an open issue about onChange(e). I added a note to my answer including a link to the issue.