# When I change a cell's background color, how can I get all cells containing the same text to change the same color in all sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with a set-list for a cover band in which I have listed all of our songs by decade on separate sheets, including a full set list on its own sheet.  When we work on new songs, I color those cells green.  I would like to see those same songs highlighted green wherever they may appear on the other sheets whenever I change color (onEdit, that is).

Here's what I've got so far pieced together from other sources:

```
function replace() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activecell = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var activecellvalue = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
var activecellcolor = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getBackground();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
var s = 0;
var cells = [];


   if (activecellvalue != 'Yes'|'No' && activecellcolor == '#00ff00'){
    for (var s=0; s < allsheets.length; s++) {
      var allcells = allsheets[s].getDataRange().getValues();
     for (var i=0; i < allcells.length; i++) { 
      for (var j=0; j < allcells[i].length; j++) {    
       if (allcells[i][j].toString().match(activecellvalue) == activecellvalue) {
        var newcells = allsheets[s].getRange(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation();
        cells.push(newcells);}

    }
   }
      allsheets[s].getRange(newcells).setBackground('#00ff00');
 // cells.push(newcells);
  Logger.log(newcells);
  Logger.log(allsheets);
  Logger.log(cells)
  }
 }
}
```

The "Yes" and "No" refer to cells containing messages in the negative or affirmative as to whether or not we have finished a song.

I have been able to get the script to color the same text in different cells in different sheets, but something still needs to be fixed which is allowing the same cell values in EVERY sheet to be highlighted, as well.

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT:
I have a working (albeit, seemingly inefficient) code that will seek out the text of an active cell elsewhere and change its cell color:

```
function colorchange() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activecell = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var activecellvalue = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
var activecellcolor = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getBackground();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
var s = 0;
var name = allsheets[s].getName();
if (activecellvalue != 'Yes'|'No' && activecellcolor == '#00ff00'){
  for (var s=0; s < allsheets.length; s++) {     
     var cells = allsheets[s].getDataRange().getValues();
     for (var i=0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
      for (var j=0; j < cells[i].length; j++) { 
       if (cells[i][j].toString().match(activecellvalue) == activecellvalue) {
         var check = cells[i][j]
         var newcells = allsheets[s].getRange(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation();
         allsheets[s].getRange(newcells).setBackground('#00ff00');
         }
    }
   }
  }
}
else if (activecellvalue != 'Yes'|'No' && activecellcolor == '#ffffff'){
      for (var s=0; s < allsheets.length; s++) {     
     var cells = allsheets[s].getDataRange().getValues();
     for (var i=0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
      for (var j=0; j < cells[i].length; j++) { 
       if (cells[i][j].toString().match(activecellvalue) == activecellvalue) {
         var check = cells[i][j]
         var newcells = allsheets[s].getRange(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation();
         allsheets[s].getRange(newcells).setBackground('#ffffff');
         }
    }       
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The problem is getting this script to trigger on a change to background color.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637901/detect-background-color-change-in-google-spreadsheet-with-apps-script), such a feature is not yet possible. Can anyone provide a potential solution?

UPDATE:

Working solution. Triggered by a drop-down menu selection.

```
function songStatus()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var curCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var curCol = curCell.getColumn();
  var curRow = curCell.getRow();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var songs = [];
  var status = sheet.getRange(curRow, 3).getValue();
  var genre = sheet.getRange(curRow, 11).getValue();


if (status == "Now")  {
  sheet.getRange(curRow, 1).setBackground('#f884ff');
  sheet.getRange(curRow, 3).setBackground('#f884ff');
  var song = sheet.getRange(curRow, 1).getValue().toString();

  for (var s=7; s < allSheets.length; s++) {     
   var row = allSheets[s].getDataRange().getLastRow();
   var col = allSheets[s].getDataRange().getLastColumn();
   var cells = allSheets[s].getDataRange().getValues();

   for (var i=0; i < row; i++) { 
    for (var j=0; j < col; j++) { 
     if (cells[i][j].toString().match(song) == song) {
       allSheets[s].getRange(i+1,j+1).setBackground('#f884ff');

      }
    }
    }
    }

  }
else if (status == "Next")
  {
    sheet.getRange(curRow, 1).setBackground('#f2a2a2');
    sheet.getRange(curRow, 3).setBackground('#f2a2a2');
    var song = sheet.getRange(curRow, 1).getValue().toString();

 for (var s=7; s < allSheets.length; s++) {     
   var row = allSheets[s].getDataRange().getLastRow();
   var col = allSheets[s].getDataRange().getLastColumn();
   var cells = allSheets[s].getDataRange().getValues();
     for (var i=0; i < row; i++) { 
     for (var j=0; j < col; j++) { 
      if (cells[i][j].toString().match(song) == song) {
       allSheets[s].getRange(i+1,j+1).setBackground('#f2a2a2');

      }
    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `onEdit` trigger only fires when an "Edit" is made by the user. However, you are right, changing the color is not considered as an edit. I would suggest a slightly different approach that would work in such a scenario. Instead of tracking your new songs by highlighting them with green and having the sheet run a script to detect if the color has been changed for that cell and then running a script to find that same song in other sheets, I'd suggest either tying your Yes/No drop-down to the onEdit function to fire the color change and the other scirpt to search for that song in other sheets, or making a new New/Old drop-down list to do that for you. Here's a small pseudo-code to do that:

```
function onEdit()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var curCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var curCol = curCell.getColumn();
  var curRow = curCell.getRow();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();

  //Assuming your New/Old column in E
  var status = sheet.getRange(curRow, 6).getValue();

  if (status == "New")
  {
    sheet.getRange(curRow, 1, 1, range.getLastColumn()).setBackgroundRGB(230,240,220);

    //Assuming your song name is in Column B
    var song = sheet.getRange(curRow, 3).getValue();

    for (var i=0; i<allSheets.length; i++)
    {
      var sRange = allSheets[i].getDataRange();
      var sData = sRange.getValues();
      var sRows = sRange.getLastRow();

      for (var j=0; j<sRows; j++)
      {
        if (sData[j][1] == song)
        {
          allSheets[i].getRange(j+1, 1, 1, sRange.getLastColumn()).setBackgroundRGB(230,240,220);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another advantage of having a code like this is that if your sheet evolves to say, track all the songs that were Old, New, In-progress, On hold or any different statuses that you could think of, and each of these had to be tracked by a color code at a glance, it's much easier to add else-if statements to do that for you.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent suggestion! This led me to a working script (see update in original post) that will change song colors in all sheets triggered by a drop-down menu for the status of the song.

Comment: Glad it helped. What I forgot to add was for the else-if functions, you could just split the code into 2 functions. The second one being something like `setCellBackground` (to make it different from setBackground which is an existing function) and pass the color hex-code and song name to be searched for. So your script would be very light and code is re-usable for each new else-if statement added to the code. But that is up to you in case you see that as a future use case.